# Saving parameters to state

Tags: wix, wix3.5

In visual studio 2010, when you use custom actions, there is a dictionary where you can save parameters that later can be loaded during uninstall, for example:

```
public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
{
    stateSaver.Add("ConnectionString", "Data Source=190.190.200.100,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;
User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;");
}

public override void Uninstall(IDictionary savedState)
{
    string connectionString = Convert.ToString(savedState["ConnectionString"]);
}
```

Is there anything similar in WiX that I can use in custom actions?

Answer (score 2):

Typically the [Remember Property Pattern](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/the-wix-toolsets-remember-property-pattern) is used to remember state across installations.